# how to get the counter column based on another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the info about buildings, a table about expenses, a table about users and a table that does the billing.
In the billing table, I need to have a counter that counts different users inside a building.
I tried to do this with the ROW_NUMBER() but I can't get the desired result.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT r.id, r.building_id AS zID,z.name AS zName,
r.user_id AS kID, k.Name AS kName,
expence_id AS uID,u.name AS uName,u.price AS uPrice,
IIF(u.unique=1,u.price,k.kvadratura * u.price) AS Balance,
r.year,r.month,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by r.user_id ORDER BY r.id) AS Counter
FROM Bill r 
INNER JOIN Expences u ON r.usluga_id = u.id
INNER JOIN Building z ON r.zgrada_id = z.id
INNER JOIN User k ON r.korisnik_id = k.id
WHERE r.building_id =7
```

This is my output:
[image]

What I would want to get is this:

For every user inside a building, counter+1.

[image]

Comment: Why in the expected output, the count is the same for the same user?  I thought you want to count up by user?

Comment: You have no 'building' column, you have additional data that does not seem to have an impact on your desired result set. Are those two users in two different buildings?

Comment: If you want help you need to provide some details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Eric This are billings. This means that I have two users in one building.And every user has two expences.

Comment: @Alexander so where's this expense information?

Comment: You only partition by user.  I may also want to partition by expense as well.

Comment: @Eric uID is the id column for expences, and uName is the name of exp,and uPrice is the price of the expense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
SELECT 
    r.id, r.building_id AS zID,z.name AS zName,
    r.user_id AS kID, k.Name AS kName,
    expence_id AS uID,u.name AS uName,u.price AS uPrice,
    IIF(u.unique=1,u.price,k.kvadratura * u.price) AS Balance,
    r.year,r.month,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(Partition by r.building_id ORDER BY r.user_id) AS Counter
FROM 
    Bill r 
    INNER JOIN Expences u ON r.usluga_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN Building z ON r.zgrada_id = z.id
    INNER JOIN User k ON r.korisnik_id = k.id
WHERE r.building_id = 7
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add expence_id to partition.

```
SELECT r.id, r.building_id AS zID,z.name AS zName,
r.user_id AS kID, k.Name AS kName,
expence_id AS uID,u.name AS uName,u.price AS uPrice,
IIF(u.unique=1,u.price,k.kvadratura * u.price) AS Balance,
r.year,r.month,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by r.user_id, expence_id ORDER BY r.id) AS Counter
FROM Bill r 
INNER JOIN Expences u ON r.usluga_id = u.id
INNER JOIN Building z ON r.zgrada_id = z.id
INNER JOIN User k ON r.korisnik_id = k.id
WHERE r.building_id =7
```